# Blazor Webassembly - Identity Server login error - on production server only

Tags: .net-core, identityserver4, blazor-webassembly

Hi i have a Blazor WebAssembly app, that i designed using mainly this Tutorial:
[Secure an ASP.NET Core Blazor WebAssembly hosted App with ID server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/hosted-with-identity-server?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio)

So whether i run it on the development machine (Windows 10, with VS installed) with IISExpress or deployed to the production IIS server everything on my scaffolded login pages works fine.

Now after deploying the project to another machine running IIS (same version) when i try to login i get this message:

There was an error trying to log you in: ''

I'm not that experienced using iis and asp so i'm still looking for a way to debug this further.

Any guesses what I'm missing?

(dotnet core runtime 3.1.7 installed on both machines)

Comment: Try to get access to the Identityserver logs and see what error you get.

Comment: Thank you - actually i did not manage to get the log working with the description on the identity server page - could not find out how to apply this to the webassembly. -- But EventViewer revealed to me that i forgot to give permissions to the IIS_IUSR on the certificate I'm using... - login is working again.